# Messages stuck in In-Flight status for SQS FIFO queue generated through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs

Actually one weird issue I am facing in terms of SQS FIFO queues generated through terraform.

Initially, I tested my application with SQS queues created manually in the AWS console, which was working fine.

Later, I generated a new SQS FIFO queue through Terraform.

I checked configurations of both the queues in terms of access policy, KMS encryption, etc. They seem to be identical.

The visibility timeout set for both the queues is 30 seconds.

Now while I am testing my application with the terraform generated queue, every message is going to in-flight status and eventually is going to DLQ. None of the messages is getting delivered to the application. I checked the log as well, there seems to be no error as well.

I have configured the maximum receive count for a given message for the normal FIFO queue to be 3, before going to DLQ.

I am not getting any clue regarding why is this happening.

For better clarity, I am adding Terraform code snippet to generate the SQS:

```
module "queue_1" {
  source                      = "./modules/terraform-aws-sqs"
  key_alias                   = 
module.sqs_encryption_queue_dlq.kms_key_alias
  service_name                = var.project_name
  team_name                   = var.team_name
  name                        = "queue_1.fifo"
  fifo_queue                  = true
  visibility_timeout_seconds  = 30
  message_retention_seconds   = 86400
  content_based_deduplication = true
  redrive_policy = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = module.dlq_1.sqs_queue_arn
    maxReceiveCount     = 3
  })
  platform_mandatory_tags = var.platform_mandatory_tags
}

module "dlq_1" {
  source                      = "./modules/terraform-aws-sqs"
  key_alias                   = 
  module.sqs_encryption_queue_dlq.kms_key_alias
  service_name                = var.project_name
  team_name                   = var.team_name
  name                        = "dlq_1.fifo"
  fifo_queue                  = true
  content_based_deduplication = true
  platform_mandatory_tags     = var.platform_mandatory_tags
}

module "sqs_encryption_queue_dlq" {
  source                  = "./modules/terraform-aws-kms2"
  key_alias               = "sqs_encryption_queue_dlq_key"
  key_description         = "KMS for queue and dlq"
  team_name               = var.team_name
  project_name            = var.project_name
  platform_mandatory_tags = var.platform_mandatory_tags
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some TF code that could allow for reproduction or some view into your actual SQS setup?

Comment: @Marcin, I have added some TF code to generate the SQS FIFO queue in the OP.

Comment: If the msgs are going to in-fligh, it means something is reading them and fails to properly delete them from the sqs. Check in console for any subscriptions such as to lambad. Maybe your app is simply failing to process the msgs? Do you have any logs for the app to check?

Comment: @Marcin, I checked in the console. There is no Lambda trigger for the queue. My concern is that message from the queue is simply not delivered to the app. To check, I have put a debugger breakpoint at the entry point of the function at the listener. But this is never getting triggered.

I have checked the logs, no message is coming for the listener for the published message.

One doubt regarding this, I am seeing too many empty receives for the queue. Is this anyway related to this issue ?

Comment: Can you go to CloudTrial event history and check API events related to the queue. If the msgs get into inflight mode, something is reading them. CT could help identify what.

Comment: @Marcin, in Cloudtrail event history, I can see event name, event time, etc. In the Event name, most of the events are GetCallerIdentity, ListPolicies, etc. I cannot find anything specific to SQS. Actually, Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think CT will not show RecieveMessage events as they will be considered data events. What if if you change the queue name?

Comment: @Marcin, It seems, I have to delete the queue and recreate it only in order to rename the queue. Actually, there are other resources also, which are used in the application, that has been created through the terraform script.

Do I have any option other than renaming the queue?

One more thing, the number of empty receives for the Terraform generated SQS FIFO queue is too high. Is it a expected behaviour for a normal FIFO SQS queue ?

Comment: What else do you have in your TF? Maybe the TF creates some resources that read your queue? And where do the messages come from?

Comment: @Marcin is there any metric to check the number of non-empty messages received successfully from the queue?

Comment: @Marcin In the TF, apart from SQS, S3bucket, KMS keys are created. The messages come from the producer module.

Comment: Sadly there is no such metrics. You can check them [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html).

Comment: @Marcin, can I raise a case to AWS support? Maybe, they can help.

Comment: If its about TF, I don't think AWS will help you much.

Comment: Okay. Will they be able to help,  if, in terms of the configuration, the manually created queue (which is behaving normally) and the TF generated queue are any different? 

 I mean, there should be some reason why the messages in TF generated queue are stuck in in-flight and going to DLQ, unlike the manually created queue.

Comment: I don't know. It does not hurt to ask.

Comment: I just tested once more with TF generated queue. The behaviour is as follows: each message from the normal queue is going to DLQ even without a being processed for once by the application.

Then all messages are eventually received from DLQ at a delay of almost 15-20 minutes.

In terms of the configuration, I have set the visibility timeout as 30 seconds and set the maximum number of receives for a given message before getting delivered to DLQ as 3.

For manually created queue with the same configuration, no message is going to DLQ and being processed almost instantly.

Comment: @Marcin, Actually I have one more queue that I have created through terraform.

This queue is working perfectly fine. Actually, the workflow is like this, I have two queues: queue_0 and queue_1. 

Each message is received from queue_0, processed, and then published to queue_1 for further processing.

Here messages are perfectly processed from queue_0 and published to queue_1. Then this weird thing starts!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no more ideas on what can be happening.

Comment: I have one more issue related to accessing the SQS queue from the Prod environment. I will post that as a separate question.